# Implement this layout using CSS float:left and float:right, or using CSS margin-left and position:absolute?

Tags: html, css, position, css-float

I want to place some annotations to the left of a topic using HTML and CSS (for example the 'status' and 'author' annotations shown in the following mockup/image):

[image: example of desired layout]

I prefer CSS instead of a table-based layout.

Annotations should be displayed **before** (to the left of) the heading, as shown above.

In the HTML, annotations should be located **after** the corresponding heading, e.g. as follows (because the information/contents associated with a topic are usually whatever is after the topic's heading):

```
<h1>This is a section title</h1>
<div class="status">approved</div>
<div class="author">chris</div>
<p>This is some text. Lorem ipsum.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum.</p>
<h1>Different section title</h1>
<div class="status">rejected</div>
<p>Lorem ipsum.</p>
```

There are (at least) two possibilities:

- [This answer uses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5086298/can-css-change-the-apparent-sequence-of-elements-e-g-using-float-or-position/5087239#5087239) `float:right`, with `float:left`
- [This answer uses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5086298/can-css-change-the-apparent-sequence-of-elements-e-g-using-float-or-position/5097132#5097132) `margin-left`, with `position:absolute` and `left`

Which of these (or any other answer) is the better way to implement this layout, and why?

Comment: Do you have any specific browser requirements?  (Basically, do you need to support IE 6, 7 or 8?  Based on your references to HTML spec's I'm assuming you are more concerned with complying to the spec than worrying about browser deficiencies.)

Comment: @peteorpeter - Yes, I'm interested in the standards, and not in browser deficiencies. I prefer CSS2.1, but might also enjoy hearing of anything CSS3-specific.

Comment: Why didn't you pick an answer...

Comment: @Hussein I didn't fully understand any answer. I apologise though, I should have come back sooner to discuss your answers with you.

Answer (score 8):

Use the solution with floats.  Absolute positioning should not be used here, because text is being positioned, and the layout is dependent upon the size of the text.  If your user changes his browser to magnify the text-size, the layout will become distorted.  You need to be especially conscious of this if you are designing pages for accessibility (consider using % instead of px for the size as well), but in general, use absolute positioning only when it is the only way to do what you want.

A great resource for understanding how to correctly use floats is [this smashing magazine article](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/05/01/css-float-theory-things-you-should-know/).  I bookmarked it a while back and I use it as a reference.

Comment: @ChrisW From all the answers, this deserved the points ????. No offense smartcaveman.

Comment: Is there a 'solution with floats' which doesn't involve doing float:right on the title and content (i.e. on everything except the annotations)? Because doing float:right changes the behaviour of margin collapse (and I don't know what else).

Comment: @Hussein It didn't totally deserve the points IMO (e.g. no working example) but the points were awarded automatically after a timeout.

Comment: @Hussein, Yes, because I answered the question that was relevant to the bounty (being why are floats a better design than absolute positioning).  That being said, I was not awarded the points by ChrisW, but I received half the points for having the highest number of votes when the bounty expired (Dagnabbit!)

Comment: @chrisW You should have picked an answer and gave credit for people who put efforts in there answers.

Comment: @smartcaveman i understand points where awarded based on highest vote. I would have expected chris to check an answer.

Comment: @ChrisW, I would probably try this with a float:left; and relative positioning as opposed to a float:right; and a float:left;

Comment: @Hussein To be honest I'm not very satisfied with any of the answers so far. People are giving various solutions, which work but without explaining why there solution is better/best. For example how is your solution better than http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5086298/implement-this-layout-using-css-floatleft-and-floatright-or-using-css-margin-l/5097132#5097132 and better than @smartcaveman 's answer who says not to use position:absolute at all?

Comment: @ChrisW, there are times when absolute positioning should be used.  (when it is the only way to accomplish what you want)

Comment: @smartcaveman - So ... if "what I want" is to a) preserve margin collapse behaviour, and b) not have to wrap the topic contents in a div, then I can't use float:right in the content. And if I then want the annotations move to the left and moved higher so that they're level with the heading, then I need to use absolute positioning. Specifying top:0 isn't bad, presumably, but you don't like specifying margin-left: 200px in one place and left:-200px in another, perhaps because you think the margin size should vary depending on the text size. Is that correct?

Comment: Other options are to float the annotations left and to float everything else right; or to place the annotations before the title in the HTML.

Answer (score 5):

No need for `position:absolute`. `float:left` will work best for this situation. `float:right` is also not needed. This solution is **cross browser compatible.** It will work in all browsers including quirks mode. Let me know how this works for you or if you need any changes.
[image]

### Check working example at http://jsfiddle.net/PyHGy/9

If HTML order is important to you where annotations must come after corresponding heading, then we need to add `position:absolute` to `.statusContainer` and then adjust the margin in `.titleContainer`. This is also a cross browser compatible solution.

### Check working example at http://jsfiddle.net/PyHGy/8/

Comment: ChrisW wrote `In the HTML, annotations should be located after the corresponding heading` . In your HTML code, annotations are before the heading.

Comment: I updated my post an included another link where annotation is located after heading. jsfiddle.net/PyHGy/8

Comment: Thank you. I see you're using several extra divs: .container and .titleContainer as well as .statusContainer.

Comment: These are used for styling and to ensure cross browser compatibility.

Comment: Is there an important difference between your 2nd answer and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5086298/implement-this-layout-using-css-floatleft-and-floatright-or-using-css-margin-l/5097132#5097132 ?

Comment: Important difference: your .titleContainer is float:left as well as margin-left, and therefore .statusContainer which is still position:absolute and left:0 doesn't need to be top:0 too.

Comment: stackoverflow.com/questions/5086298/… is a mess.

Comment: "It's a mess" ... because it's difficult to read? Because it renders badly in some browser[s]?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can achieve what you're looking for with css, i.e.: floats. However, you're going to need to specify width for your block elements.

Play with it. At its simplest level, set all widths to 50% (maybe less depending on padding) and add float:left and float:right where applicable.

Comment: In addition, wrapping each "section" with a `<div>` and setting it's `overflow: hidden;` will keep the sections from falling into each other.

Comment: @Jeremy Do you recommend `overflow: hidden`, or `overflow: auto`? The spec says that `auto` is UA-dependent. If there's a lot of annotation I don't want to hide it, I want to push down the section below it.

Comment: It doesn't really matter if you don't have a height property set. However, I usually don't like scroll bars magically appearing so that's why I use hidden. http://www.quirksmode.org/css/overflow.html

Comment: Can you comment on whether [using float:left](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5086298/can-css-change-the-apparent-sequence-of-elements-e-g-using-float-or-position/5087239#5087239) or [using position:absolute](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5086298/can-css-change-the-apparent-sequence-of-elements-e-g-using-float-or-position/5097132#5097132) is a better solution?

Comment: @ChrisW, I gave an explanation of why a float is better than a div in this circumstance.  In addition, you may run into some problems with small windows and different types of screens if you use the 'width:50%', as suggested above.  Please see the article in my post for explanation on how to properly implement this.

Comment: The "50%-less-padding" was merely for "play" purposes so that the floats wouldn't stack. He can use fixed widths just as easily.

Comment: @antisanity, I was only trying to make ChrisW aware of the possible side effects.  In general I think your answer points him in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

Untested, but this should work. If it doesn't I can edit to fix.

HTML:

```
<div class="section">
  <h1>This is a section title</h1>
  <div class="info">
     <div class="status">approved</div>
     <div class="author">chris</div>
  </div>
  <div class="body">
    <p>This is some text. Lorem ipsum.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.section {
  overflow: auto; /* so that the height and width calculate floats properly, otherwise the height will be nothing since all elements are floating */
  width: 700px; /* or total width */
}

/* this could be simplified if you didn't want the <h1> right near the .info, by putting the <h1> inside .body and removing the .section h1 from this */
.section h1, .section .body {
  float: right; 
  width: 500px; /* whatever */
}

.section .info {
  float: left;
  width: 200px; /* whatever */
}
```

Comment: This works for some page widths but not others. If the total page width is less than 700 px then the info stays on the left but drops vertically to below the heading. If the total page width is greater than 1000px then the body jumps to the left-hand side instead of staying aligned under the heading.

Comment: Using relative widths e.g. 20% and 80% avoids this problem.

Comment: I didn't realize that the info would move upwards (or, that the heading would move downwards) so that the info and the heading are at the same vertical location. From which part/phrase of the [CSS specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/) should I have predicted/expected that?

Comment: You make it not work like that by replacing the `float: right` on the `.section h1` with a `padding-left: 200px; clear: all`.

Comment: @aharon Specifically rule #8: "A floating box must be placed as high as possible."

Comment: "Have I answered your question completely" - Yes; thank you. I posted a [slightly-revised answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5086298/can-css-change-the-apparent-sequence-of-elements-e-g-using-float-or-position/5087239#5087239). And as I [posted in a comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5086298/can-css-change-the-apparent-sequence-of-elements-e-g-using-float-or-position/5086328#5086328) to @Jeremy I don't know exactly what `overflow: auto` does given that the spec only says that it's "UA-dependent".

Comment: Using IE, `overflow: auto` does what I want it to do: it pushes the .section below this .section downwards, if the .info is longer than the .body.

Comment: Actually I think I'll use [a different solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5086298/can-css-change-the-apparent-sequence-of-elements-e-g-using-float-or-position/5097132#5097132), because `float:right` prevents margins collapsing between the floated-right blocks.

Comment: Can you comment on whether [using float:left](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5086298/can-css-change-the-apparent-sequence-of-elements-e-g-using-float-or-position/5087239#5087239) or [using position:absolute](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5086298/can-css-change-the-apparent-sequence-of-elements-e-g-using-float-or-position/5097132#5097132) is a better solution?

Comment: Thanks. Usually, using `floats` is better than absolute positioning because it let's your layout be more fluid. Using `overflow: auto` is used to explicitly set the overflow, and thus prevent the margin-collapse.

Comment: My reason why I thought position:absolute might be better is that I quite like margin collapse. I use and rely on margin collapse to get nice inter-block spacing in the normal flow, and having float:right on most of the section content prevents the nice margin collapse that I'd usually get.

Answer (score 1):

I'm of the opinion that there is not a holistic "Right" answer here. There are a lot of good comments and examples in this post, as well as, pros and cons between float and position.

I offer a working example that relies on CSS inheritance (and float). It makes the HTML markup very trim, accessibility friendly, and very easy to read long after launch when editing/revisions come due. HTML follows:

```
<div class="author">
    <h3>This is a section title</h3>
    <span class="status">
        <p>(status: approved)</p>
        <p>(author: chris)</p>
    </span>
    <p>This is some text. Lorem ipsum. Lorem ipsum.</p>
</div>
```

Working code here: http://jsfiddle.net/kz8dG/4/.

Answer (score 1):

As others said you should use float in this case. I think if you look at the code later it will be much easier to understand if you use floated elements.

I suggest you use liquid layout for this, not setting the width of the section to a constant px: http://jsfiddle.net/9j5jd/

Advantages of this solution:

- The sections use `100%-(width of status text)` width of the container
- Order of html elements are unchanged

You may set the status width to `%`, or `em`, I used `150px`. I didn't set a constant height to sections, you may do that if you want to.

Codes (same as jsfiddle): HTML:

```
<div class="section">
    <div class="header"><h1>This is a section title</h1></div>
    <div class="status">approved</div>
    <div class="author">chris</div>
    <div class="content"><div class="inner">
        <p>This is some text. Lorem ipsum.This is some text. Lorem ipsum.This is some text. Lorem ipsum.This is some text. Lorem ipsum.This is some text. Lorem ipsum.This is some text. Lorem ipsum.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum.</p>
        </div></div>
</div>
<div class="section">
    <div class="header"><h1>Different section title</h1></div>
    <div class="status">rejected</div>
    <div class="content"><div class="inner">
        <p>Lorem ipsum.</p>
        </div></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
/* Position */
.header, .content {
    float: right;
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: -150px;
}
h1, .inner {
    margin-left: 150px;
}
h1 {
    clear: both; 
}
.status, .author {
    float: left;
    width: 130px;  
    clear: left;
    text-align: right;
    padding-right: 20px;
}

/* Decoration */
h1 {
    color: #365F91;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    margin-bottom: 0.3em;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.status, .author {
    font-size: 0.8em; 
}
.status:before {
    content:"(status: ";
}
.author:before {
    content:"(author: ";    
}
.status:after, .author:after {
    content:")";
}
.section {
    float: left;
    margin-top: 0.5em; 
}
```

Comment: Using float right means that margins between floated-right elements don't collapse as they usually would; and, you have an extra .content div to wrap the content to ensure that all the content is floated right. Whereas with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5086298/implement-this-layout-using-css-floatleft-and-floatright-or-using-css-margin-l/5097132#5097132 I just position the .info to the left, and the layout of the rest (including margin collapse) is unaffected (except pushed to the right using left-margin).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution based on [aharon's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5086298/can-css-change-the-apparent-sequence-of-elements-e-g-using-float-or-position/5086330#5086330). This is a slight refinement, which:

- Uses the `.section > *` child selector to float everything right (which removes the need to explicitly reference the `.section h1` heading element[s], and the `.section .body` div)
- Removes the `<div class="body">` from the HTML
- Adds `.section > *:first-child { margin-top: 0 }` so that the heading and the `.info` have the same `margin-top` value (any such margin should be applied to the `.section` instead of only to the heading)

Here's the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
    .section
        {   overflow: auto; }
    .section > *
        {
            float: right;
            width: 80%; /* whatever */
        }
    .section > *:first-child 
        {
            margin-top: 0
        }
    .section .info
        {   float: left;   width: 20%; /* whatever */ }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="section">
    <h1>This is a section title</h1>
    <div class="info">
        <div class="status">approved</div>
        <div class="author">chris</div>
    </div>
    <p>This is some text. Lorem ipsum.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum.</p>
</div>
<div class="section">
    <h1>Next section title</h1>
    <div class="info">
        <div class="status">rejected</div>
    </div>
    <p>This is some text. Lorem ipsum.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum.</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Or use absolute widths, as shown in aharon's answer, instead of relative widths.

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately, using `float` to move most of the content to the right, as shown in other answers, has an unwanted side-effect: it prevents the usual ['margin collapse](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#collapsing-margins)', which happens to elements which are in the normal flow but which does not happen to floated elements.

An alternative is as follows.

Create a large margin using `margin-left` (don't use `left` because that would result in the block being too wide, overflowing the edge on the right-hand side; whereas increasing the margin makes a corresponding decrease to the content area). And, specify `relative` positioning (with a zero left/right/top/bottom offset) to create/start a new stacking context, so that the `.section .info` will be positioned relative to each `.section`:

```
.section
    {
        overflow: visible;
        position: relative;
        margin-left: 200px;
    }
```

Use `absolute` positioning to place the `.section .info` to the left and top of its containing block:

```
.section .info
    {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0px;
        left: -200px;
        width: 180px;
        height: 100%
        text-align: right;
        font-size: smaller;
    }
```

The absolute positioning of the `.section .info` takes it out of the normal flow, and margins collapse between the `<h1>` and the `<p>`.

Here's the complete example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./user.css" /> 
    <style type="text/css">
    .section
        {
            overflow: visible;
            position: relative;
            margin-left: 200px;
        }
    .section > *:first-child 
        {
            margin-top: 0
        }
    .section .info
        {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0px;
            left: -200px;
            width: 180px;
            height: 100%
            text-align: right;
            font-size: smaller;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="section">
    <h1>1st section title</h1>
    <div class="info">
        <div class="status">approved</div>
        <div class="author">chris</div>
    </div>
    <p>This is some text. Lorem ipsum.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum.</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```